# Problem with "move to chat" function?

Tags: bug, chat

I seem to be having a problem with the "move to chat" button. In a recent question, I received the "consider moving to chat" prompt, and I clicked the proffered button; however, it didn't work. Sometimes I got an error message ("move to chat failed"), and other times I was simply sent back to the top of the page. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature that protects you from using the chat... :P

Comment: Also, have you tried running a different browser, a safe-mode browser (i.e. without extensions such as adblockers or so) or a different computer?